# How to change iconTint of a specific item in BottomNavigationView

Tags: java, android, xml, bottomnavigationview

I am trying to change the `iconTint` of the `favorites` `menuItem` in the `bottomNavigationView`.

To achieve so, I've tried the following:

- Creating a `selector` with colors
- Creating a `selector` with drawables
- Programatically setting icon drawable
- programatically setting `iconItemTint` of `bottomNavigationView` to null
- Using colored icon drawables, instead of `iconItemTint`
- Setting the icon of `favorites` to the drawable selector
- Setting the `background` of `favorites` to the desired color
- Setting `iconTint` of `favorites` to desired color

None of the above solutions worked for me. Then I figured that it might be because I'm using `com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView` instead of `android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView`

My bottomNavigationView

```
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        app:itemTextColor="#232323"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```

My bottom_nav_menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    ...
    <item
        android:title="Favorites"
        android:id="@+id/btn_favorites"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:background="@color/red_heart"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_red"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
   ...
```

Here is a screenshot of my app:

[image: App ScreenShot]

The selected color is blue for all `menuItems`. I want the `favorites` to have the color `#ff4444` (pale red)  when selected.

Comment: you want only favorite should tint #ff444 ?

Comment: `com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView` is the up-to-date version from the age of androidx; `android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView` is the older support-library version. Might be that the functionality you want is still not provided by the google version of BottomNavigation; in which case you could go with a different implementation (e.g. https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation - although that's just an example, there are others. Been using this one for a while now).

Comment: @Blackmamba yes.

Comment: what you have done for for tint on single selection of favorite button ? @SowingFiber

Comment: @Blackmamba I used `android:iconTint="#ff4444"` in my `favorites` item. I also tried using `android:background`. Then, Programatically, I also tried setting the icon color to a colored icon.

Comment: @SowingFiber how did you solve this? The solution provided by Tarun will change the icon for every highlighted item and not only the favorites icon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasted a lot of time searching the correct answer to "How to change color of **one specific** icon of Bottom Navigation View" and I resolved this by myself. Here is the example:

```
val view = viewBinding.bottomNavigationView.menuView as NavigationBarMenuView
val itemToChange = view.findViewById<NavigationBarItemView>(R.id."item_to_change_id")
itemToChange.setIconTintList(    
    ColorStateList.valueOf(
        ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext,R.color."color you need")
    )
)
```

I didn't try this with `android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView`, but with `com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView` it works correctly :)

Answer (score -1):

```
 <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bootom_text_color"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bootom_text_color"
        android:background="@color/bottom_color"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation" />
```

create colour.xml in values

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="#FFFF00" />
    <item android:color="@color/white"  /> </selector>
```

Comment: I don't know, why this is marked as the correct answer. This is clearly not the correct answer, because OP was asking to only tint _one item_ differently. This code just tints all selected items the same color.

Comment: updated the correct answer. at that time, it was the only solution.